# How to tell if user entered text into a textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I am doing some form validation, and I have a textarea that has an initial placeholder in it, and I'm trying to check if the user has entered any data into the textarea.

If I check using jquery `.text()` it doesn't see the text being added at the browser level, and if I use `.val()` nothing is updated there in the first place.  So what's the proper way to do this check prior to submitting the form?

```
<div>
   <textarea class="myUserText"></textarea>
</div>

function validateForm(){
   if($('.myUserText').text()==""){
        //do something here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> and if I use .val() nothing is updated there in the first place. So what's the proper way to do this check prior to submitting the form?

`val` is the correct thing to check, and will be `!= ""` if the user has entered something in the textarea.

Of course, the thing they've entered could be just a newline, which may not be what you want. So you might consider:

```
if($('.myUserText').val().replace(/^\s+/, "") === "")
```

...which ignores leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` should work. Catch the submit event as well:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if (!$('.myUserText').val() == '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        // The form won't submit
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, still not working for me.  Will make a difference if I have a placeholder for textarea?

Comment: @JSilva: What does `console.log($('.myUserText').val())` output to the console?

Comment: Nevermind.  This worked!!  Thanks.  Think I had an issue with my selector.  I changed it to select based on the class instead of name.  Good to know it will work with a placeholder though.

Answer (score 0):

... or if you are interested in using some of the latest HTML5 options:

- use form validation for the various input fields (eg email, url, req'd: http://bit.ly/Z8ZEHe
- use modernizr to check if the visitor's browser supports HTML5 forms, and if it doesn't load a fallback polyfill: 
  http://modernizr.com
  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Good luck!